# BGE: "Record Animation" for just one object

Tags: game-engine

I'd like to use the "Record Animation" feature in the Game Engine where movements by an object at runtime are recorded to the object's animation, but for just one object and not for the entire scene. Is it possible?

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry for writing "render animation" instead of "record animation". The problem has been fixed now.

Comment: Try selecting it, and moving it to a different layer.
Select, then click M, then move it to an extra layer. It should render on its own now. I'm not sure how the Game Engine works, though.

Comment: @BookWyrm17 Sorry for that. I meant "Record Animation".

Answer (score 1):

Animations are recorded only for objects with Physics Type: Rigid Body & Soft Body. If you don't want to record animations, you can use Physics Type: Character.